# Fast automated spellchecking

Tags: search, nlp, spell-checking

I have a really big (~50MB) file of Spanish sentences. I want to check which of these don't contain foreign words. To achieve that, I am planning to filter out sentences that contain words that don't exist in the spellchecker dictionary. Does such a tool exist? Is it worth to play around with search trees and hash tables to create an efficient spellchecker myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/), the spell checker of OpenOffice, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. It is an open source C++ library with bindings for Java, Perl, Python, .NET and Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You ca try the spell checker in Whoosh, via a short python script as described here:
http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/spelling.html

or use Pyenchant:
http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html